# Getting "permission denied" when mounting /var/run/docker.sock via hostPath volume

Tags: kubernetes

Because I'm too stupid to run `sysbox` like [this excellent article](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) suggests, I'm trying to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` directly into the container from the host via `hostPath` to build Docker images in a Jenkins container.

Simple as this:

```yaml
  volumeMounts:
    - name: docker-sock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
```

This works, but when trying to run the Docker CLI inside the container I get:

```bash
$ docker version

Client:
 Version:           20.10.16
 // ...
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

The user inside the container is:

```bash
$ id

uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)
```

But the file has these permissions:

```bash
$ ls -la /var/run/docker.sock

srw-rw---- 1 root 998 0 Jun  6 15:23 /var/run/docker.sock
```

I do have root on the host node and security is not much of a concern since the Jenkins can only be accessed via VPN.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Using `chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock` on the host does work, but maybe there's a better option?